# Make a bash script that refresh values without scrolling down the terminal like TOP command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to set a bash script to refresh the screen with variable values like TOP command?

To show the variable value I use:

```
echo "$var"
```

But it prints a new line, instead of I would like something that refresh the screen

[image]

How to achieve this?

Comment: `watch your_script.sh`

Comment: If you want to generate cursor-movement codes appropriate for your current terminal, `tput` can do that for you, with a very wide range of options -- moving in a specific direction relative to current position, moving to a specific spot, etc. Cache output from the specific tput invocations you need during your script's initialization, and you'll have a much lower-overhead/higher-performance approach than anything based on `watch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use `watch`:

```
watch date
```

You can also just call `clear` before each iteration. Here, all the output from `clear` and any commands are collected as a form of double buffering to reduce flickering:

```
show_things() {
  date
  uname -a
  echo "Your lucky number is $RANDOM"
}

while sleep 1
do
  printf '%s\n' "$(clear; show_things)"
done
```

Comment: Hmm. I may have overstated the portably-available capabilities -- we can *store* the current TTY state using only `tput`-exposed functionality, and likewise switch back to what was stored, but if we can't write to the backbuffer while it isn't displayed, that's a lot less useful.